# How to enable sound on Base Game Activity in Andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game using Andengine , I am using a `Base Game Activity` with multiple scenes. I want to load a background music in it.But **I dont know how to enable sound in engine** while using `Base Game Activity`.I found this code in net to enable sound .

`return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera).setNeedsMusic(true));`

But this one is written in  `onLoadScene()` and I dont know how to impliment `onLoadScene()` in basegame actvity.Do I can override  `onLoadScene()` in base game activity or is there any other ways to achive this please help me...

Any Suggestions are Valid to me and Advanced thanks to alll....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like

```
final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
        new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
```

and/or

```
engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true);
```

Comment: Thank you , Thank you Sir... that's worked .I am working on my first game and I am using  Tons of tips from your answers and blog Again you are here to help me I don't know how to say thanks to you...A lot of thanks Sir.